# Configuration section null in Startup but populates in service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I come across some strangeness while debugging another issue and wondering if someone with more knowledgeable could explain. Here is some quick test code (I apologies for any errors)

AppSetting

```
{  
  "A": {
    "B": 123,
    "C": "ABC"
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var config1 = Configuration.GetSection("A");
    //config1.value <- Null
    var config2 = Configuration.GetSection("A:B");
    //config2.value <- 123
    var config3 = Configuration.GetSection("A:C");
    //config3.value <- "ABC"
    services.Configure<ABC>(config1);
    services.AddTransient<ABCService>();
}

public class ABC
{
    public int B {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;}
}

public class ABCService
{
        public ABCService(IOptions<ABC> abcConfig)
        {
            //abcConfig.Value.B <- 123
            //abcConfig.Value.C <- "ABC"
        }
}
```

Why is `config1.value` null in `ConfigureServices` but after dependency injection `abcConfig` in `ABCService` has values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config1.value` is `null` simply because, in your example JSON, there is no *value* for `A`. The configuration system works with simple key value pairs. For example, in your built `Configuration` object, you have the following (key => value):

```
A =>
A:B => 123
A:C => ABC
```

You can see this for yourself if you run the following sample code, which generates the output shown above:

```
Configuration.AsEnumerable()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", x.Key, x.Value));
```

This shows that the value for `A` is `null`, which is what you have described. There are values for both `A:B` and `A:C`, which are part of the `A` *section* as denoted by the `:` hierarchy separator. When you use `services.Configure`, it's really just matching anything under `A:` against your `ABC` class, where it finds `B` and `C` accordingly.

By using `GetSection("A")`, you've created a different view of your `Configuration` instance that will only include anything rooted at `A`. In your example, it's the same in both cases as you only have `A`.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) do a great job of describing how the configuration system works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constructor to your startup class and put IConfiguration as a dependency. that will be the resolved configuration object. You can then use that in your ConfigureServices method.

You can see an example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1